# How can I have Columns of a Entity in a superclass?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to have some properties in a superclass / base class of Entities.
The simplest example of what I want to achieve is this:

```
<?php
class BaseEntity{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @var int internal ID
     */
    private int $id;

    public function getId(): int{
        return $this->id;
    }
}
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="someentities")
 */
class SomeEntity extends BaseEntity{
    // more stuff
}
```

Is there a way to do this with doctrine ORM? The above example doesn't work, Doctrine does not find the primary key in SomeEntity.
You can kindof do this by making the BaseEntity a Entity itself, but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is use [Mapped Superclasses](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses).
For the example above it would look like this:

```
<?php
/** @ORM\MappedSuperclass */
class BaseEntity{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @var int internal ID
     */
    private int $id;

    public function getId(): int{
        return $this->id;
    }
}
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="someentities")
 */
class SomeEntity extends BaseEntity{
    // more stuff
}
```

If you stumbled across this question you might also be looking for [Embeddables](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/embeddables.html#separating-concerns-using-embeddables), depending on what you are trying to accomplish.